# AFP Client (afpfs-ng) ls: reading directory .: Input/output error, CentOS 7 & MacOS Sierra

Tags: centos, mount, osx, file-sharing, fuse

I need a Client in **CentOS 7** to get access to a shared folder of **Mac Sierra** using **AFP** protocol.

I installed [afpfs-ng-0.8.2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/simonvetter/afpfs-ng/master/afpfs-ng-0.8.2.tar.gz), <strike>previously [fuse-2.9.7](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/releases/download/fuse-2.9.7/fuse-2.9.7.tar.gz) from sources following the  [fuse-2.9.4 instructions](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.8/postlfs/fuse.html)</strike>

```
$ sudo yum install fuse fuse-devel readline-devel libgcrypt-devel gmp-devel
```

Here the working installation.

> Installing **afpfs-ng** tar.gz source version!

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/simonvetter/afpfs-ng/master/afpfs-ng-0.8.2.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf afpfs-ng-0.8.2.tar.gz  
$ cd afpfs-ng/
$ ./configure && make && sudo make install && sudo ldconfig
```

> Checking the installation!

```
$ killall -r afpfsd ; afp_client status
afpfsd: no process found
The afpfs daemon does not appear to be running for uid 1000, let me start it for you
AFPFS Version: 0.8.2
UAMs compiled in: Cleartxt Passwrd, No User Authent, Randnum Exchange, 2-Way Randnum Exchange, DHCAST128, DHX2
$
```

> Executing (mounting the AFP shared folder by mac)

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/AFP_ADATAHD

$ sudo mount_afp afp://theUser:thePassword@192.168.0.14/ADATAHD /media/AFP_ADATAHD
sudo: mount_afp: command not found
$

$ mount_afp afp://theUser:thePassword@192.168.0.14/ADATAHD /media/AFP_ADATAHD
Mounting 192.168.0.14 from ADATAHD on /media/AFP_ADATAHD
Unmounting volume ADATAHD from /media/AFP_ADATAHD
FUSE reported the following error:
fusermount: user has no write access to mountpoint /media/AFP_ADATAHD
Unknown error 1, 1.
$
```

I think *sudo* should work, but not!

> Working with *root* user!

```
# mount_afp afp://theUser:thePassword@192.168.0.14/ADATAHD /media/AFP_ADATAHD
The afpfs daemon does not appear to be running for uid 0, let me start it for you
Mounting 192.168.0.14 from ADATAHD on /media/AFP_ADATAHD
Mounting of volume ADATAHD of server theUser MacBook succeeded.
#
```

**THE REAL PROBLEM:**

---

LISTING AFP DIRECTORY ON MACOS SIDE!

```
# ls -al /Volumes/ADATAHD/SoftwareDownloads/WIN/
total 8756680
drwx------  28 _unknown  _unknown         952 May 10 14:21 .
drwxr-xr-x   9 _unknown  _unknown         306 May 10 14:20 ..
-rwx------@  1 _unknown  _unknown       10244 May 10 14:20 .DS_Store
-rwx------   1 _unknown  _unknown          94 May 10 14:21 .directory
drwxr-xr-x   3 _unknown  _unknown         102 Apr 24 22:15 7ULive
-rwx------   1 _unknown  _unknown    20903280 Sep  2  2016 BCompare-4.1.8.21575.exe
-rw-r--r--@  1 _unknown  _unknown       28268 Mar 19 22:13 C9E72A428218A05F34C66182511C5C48EA015FD0.torrent
-rwx------@  1 _unknown  _unknown     9367104 Oct  2  2016 ConnectToWindowsFromMAC - RDC_2.1.1_ALL.dmg
drwxrwxrwx   3 _unknown  _unknown         102 Mar 29 07:32 Development
drwxrwxrwx   7 _unknown  _unknown         238 Apr 30 21:18 GRTMPVOL_ES_ISO
drwx------   8 _unknown  _unknown         272 Sep  3  2016 KMSpico 10.2.0 FINAL
drwxrwxrwx   4 _unknown  _unknown         136 Apr 25 19:09 Microsoft Office 2016 VL ProPlus Spanish (x86-x64) March 2016
drwxr-xr-x   7 _unknown  _unknown         238 Mar 20 17:10 Nitro 11.0.3.17
drwx------   8 _unknown  _unknown         272 Oct  5  2016 Nitro Pro 10.5.9.9 ES
drwx------  13 _unknown  _unknown         442 Mar 26 21:14 Office 2016
-rwx------@  1 _unknown  _unknown    53118336 Aug 31  2016 Open-Sankore_Windows_2.5.1.zip
-rwx------   1 _unknown  _unknown    11304960 Sep 10  2016 SmartView.msi
drwxr-xr-x   4 _unknown  _unknown         136 May  1 13:12 WIN XP SP3
-rw-r--r--   1 _unknown  _unknown  3170525184 Apr 30 00:20 WINVISTA SP2 32 Bit.www.auyanet.net.iso
drwx------  19 _unknown  _unknown         646 Mar 29 11:53 Windows 10 Enterprise
drwx------  21 _unknown  _unknown         714 Apr 24 00:04 Windows Programas
-rw-r--r--   1 _unknown  _unknown   569790128 Apr 30 21:47 Windows XP SP3 Original.rar
-rw-r--r--   1 _unknown  _unknown     1735400 Apr 24 14:52 adksetup.exe
-rw-r--r--   1 _unknown  _unknown          26 Apr 24 14:52 adksetup.exe:Zone.Identifier
-rwx------@  1 _unknown  _unknown    77404656 Sep  6  2016 gimp-2.8.18-setup.exe
-rwx------@  1 _unknown  _unknown   203084344 Oct  4  2016 jdk-8u101-windows-x64.exe
-rwx------@  1 _unknown  _unknown   230883184 Oct  4  2016 netbeans-8.2-windows.exe
-rw-r--r--@  1 _unknown  _unknown   135240048 Apr 24 00:25 serviio-1.8-win-setup.exe
#
```

---

LISTING AFP DIRECTORY ON LINUX SIDE

```
# ls -al /media/AFP_ADATAHD/SoftwareDownloads/WIN/
ls: reading directory /media/AFP_ADATAHD/SoftwareDownloads/WIN/: Input/output error
total 213
drwx------ 28 root root     908 May 10 09:21 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root     262 May 10 09:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root      58 Apr 24 17:15 7ULive
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1735400 Apr 24 09:52 adksetup.exe
-rwx------  1 root root      94 May 10 09:21 .directory
-rwx------  1 root root   10244 May 10 09:20 .DS_Store
#
```

I put all my procedure and I want to know how solve this message:

**ls: reading directory /media/AFP_ADATAHD/SoftwareDownloads/WIN/: Input/output error**

---

**EDIT 1**
 
A comparison with samba performance will be useful.

---

LISTING USING SAMBA VERSION ON LINUX SIDE

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/SMB_ADATAHD
$ sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.14/ADATAHD /media/SMB_ADATAHD -o username=theUser,password=thePassword,domain=BZ,rw


# ls -al /media/SMB_ADATAHD/SoftwareDownloads/WIN/
total 4378504
drwx------ 29 nobody nobody          0 May 10 23:58 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 nobody nobody          0 May 10 14:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 nobody nobody          0 Apr 24 22:15 7ULive
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody    1735400 Apr 24 14:52 adksetup.exe
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody         26 Apr 24 14:52 adksetup.exe:Zone.Identifier
-rwx------  1 nobody nobody   20903280 Sep  2  2016 BCompare-4.1.8.21575.exe
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody      28268 Mar 19 22:13 C9E72A428218A05F34C66182511C5C48EA015FD0.torrent
-rwx------  1 nobody nobody    9367104 Oct  2  2016 ConnectToWindowsFromMAC - RDC_2.1.1_ALL.dmg
drwxrwxrwx  3 nobody nobody          0 Mar 29 07:32 Development
-rwx------  1 nobody nobody         94 May 10 14:21 .directory
-rwx------  1 nobody nobody      10244 May 10 14:20 .DS_Store
-rwx------  1 nobody nobody   77404656 Sep  6  2016 gimp-2.8.18-setup.exe
drwxrwxrwx  7 nobody nobody          0 Apr 30 21:18 GRTMPVOL_ES_ISO
-rwx------  1 nobody nobody  203084344 Oct  4  2016 jdk-8u101-windows-x64.exe
drwx------  8 nobody nobody          0 Sep  3  2016 KMSpico 10.2.0 FINAL
drwxrwxrwx  4 nobody nobody          0 Apr 25 19:09 Microsoft Office 2016 VL ProPlus Spanish (x86-x64) March 2016
-rwx------  1 nobody nobody  230883184 Oct  4  2016 netbeans-8.2-windows.exe
drwxr-xr-x  7 nobody nobody          0 Mar 20 17:10 Nitro 11.0.3.17
drwx------  8 nobody nobody          0 Oct  5  2016 Nitro Pro 10.5.9.9 ES
drwx------ 13 nobody nobody          0 Mar 26 21:14 Office 2016
-rwx------  1 nobody nobody   53118336 Aug 31  2016 Open-Sankore_Windows_2.5.1.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody  135240048 Apr 24 00:25 serviio-1.8-win-setup.exe
-rwx------  1 nobody nobody   11304960 Sep 10  2016 SmartView.msi
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody     165754 May 11 07:43 testdisk.log
drwx------ 19 nobody nobody          0 Mar 29 11:53 Windows 10 Enterprise
drwx------ 21 nobody nobody          0 Apr 24 00:04 Windows Programas
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody  569790128 Apr 30 21:47 Windows XP SP3 Original.rar
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody 3170525184 Apr 30 00:20 WINVISTA SP2 32 Bit.www.auyanet.net.iso
drwxr-xr-x  4 nobody nobody          0 May  1 13:12 WIN XP SP3
#
```

Using Samba Client the problem doesn't raise up!